# How to feed an LSTM/GRU model multiple independent Time Series?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting

In Order to explain it simply: I have 53 Oil Producing wells measurements, each well has been measured each day for 6 years, we recorded multiple variables (*Pressure, water production, gas production...etc*), and our main component(The one we want to study and forecast) is the **Oil production rate**. How can I Use all the data to train my model of LSTM/GRU knowing that the Oil wells are independent and that the measurments have been done in the same time for each one?

Answer (score 0):

The knowledge that "the measurments have been done in the same time for each [well]" is not necessary if you want to assume that the wells are independent. (Why do you think that that knowledge is useful?)

So if the wells are considered independent, treat them as individual samples. Split them into a training set, validation set, and test set, as usual. Train a usual LSTM or GRU on the training set.

By the way, you might want to use the attention mechanism instead of recurrent networks. It is easier to train and usually yields comparable results.

Even convolutional networks might be good enough. See methods like WaveNet if you suspect long-range correlations.

Comment: I am new to LSTM knowledge, So I shall just stack them together as if they were one dataset ? wouldn't that create a disturbance in the time series ?

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTaibi Treat them as individual samples. Not as one sample. This is not specific to recurrent networks, this is general deep learning stuff. Like if you have several images in an image dataset. You don't concatenate them along the channels dimension nor along the time/space dimension. You treat them as separate samples.

Answer (score 0):

These well measurements sound like specific and independent events. I work in the finance sector. We always look at different stocks, and each stocks specific time neries using LSTM, but not 10 stocks mashed up together. Here's some code to analyze a specific stock. Modify the code to suit your needs.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

start = '2019-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'

tickers = ['GOOG']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

for col in df.columns: 
    print(col) 
    
#used for setting the output figure size
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10
#to normalize the given input data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
#to read input data set (place the file name inside  ' ') as shown below


df['Adj Close'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()

ntrain = 80
df_train = df.head(int(len(df)*(ntrain/100)))
ntest = -80
df_test = df.tail(int(len(df)*(ntest/100)))


#importing the packages 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

#dataframe creation
seriesdata = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
new_seriesdata = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date','Adj Close'])
length_of_data=len(seriesdata)
for i in range(0,length_of_data):
    new_seriesdata['Date'][i] = seriesdata['Date'][i]
    new_seriesdata['Adj Close'][i] = seriesdata['Adj Close'][i]
#setting the index again
new_seriesdata.index = new_seriesdata.Date
new_seriesdata.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)
#creating train and test sets this comprises the entire data’s present in the dataset
myseriesdataset = new_seriesdata.values
totrain = myseriesdataset[0:255,:]
tovalid = myseriesdataset[255:,:]
#converting dataset into x_train and y_train
scalerdata = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scale_data = scalerdata.fit_transform(myseriesdataset)
x_totrain, y_totrain = [], []
length_of_totrain=len(totrain)
for i in range(60,length_of_totrain):
    x_totrain.append(scale_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_totrain.append(scale_data[i,0])
x_totrain, y_totrain = np.array(x_totrain), np.array(y_totrain)
x_totrain = np.reshape(x_totrain, (x_totrain.shape[0],x_totrain.shape[1],1))


#LSTM neural network
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_totrain.shape[1],1)))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1))
lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adadelta')
lstm_model.fit(x_totrain, y_totrain, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
#predicting next data stock price
myinputs = new_seriesdata[len(new_seriesdata) - (len(tovalid)+1) - 60:].values
myinputs = myinputs.reshape(-1,1)
myinputs  = scalerdata.transform(myinputs)
tostore_test_result = []
for i in range(60,myinputs.shape[0]):
    tostore_test_result.append(myinputs[i-60:i,0])
tostore_test_result = np.array(tostore_test_result)
tostore_test_result = np.reshape(tostore_test_result,(tostore_test_result.shape[0],tostore_test_result.shape[1],1))
myclosing_priceresult = lstm_model.predict(tostore_test_result)
myclosing_priceresult = scalerdata.inverse_transform(myclosing_priceresult)
    
totrain = df_train
tovalid = df_test

#predicting next data stock price
myinputs = new_seriesdata[len(new_seriesdata) - (len(tovalid)+1) - 60:].values


#  Printing the next day’s predicted stock price. 
print(len(tostore_test_result));
print(myclosing_priceresult);
```

Final result:

```
1
[[1396.532]]
```